# Better way to instantiate multiple different classes in Java via factories

Tags: java, factory

Say you have a lot of similar classes that may get instantiated at any point. One obvious way to write this would be a whole slew of conditionals:

```
public static Common factory(String key, InstantiationObj instantiationObj) {

  if( key == "A") {
    return new TypeA(instantiationObj);
  }
  else if( key == "B") {
    return new TypeB(instantiationObj);
  }
  else if( key == "C" ) {
    return new TypeC(instantiationObj);
  } 
  else if( key == "D" ) {
    return new TypeD(instantiationObj);
  }
  else {
    return new DefaultClass(instantiationObj);
  }

}
```

I like to avoid all the conditionals though. In Java I got this working:

```
public static <T extends Common> T factory(String key, InstantiationObj instantiationObj) throws Exception {  
  Class[] cArg = new Class[1];
  cArg[0] = InstantiationObj.class;
  HashMap<String, Class> potentialClasses = new HashMap<>();
  
  potentialClasses.put("A", TypeA.class);
  potentialClasses.put("B", TypeB.class);
  potentialClasses.put("C", TypeC.class);
  potentialClasses.put("D", TypeD.class);

  Class<T> classType = potentialClasses.getOrDefault(key, DefaultClass.class);
  return classType.getDeclaredConstructor(cArg).newInstance(instantiationObj);
}
```

This is much easier to test, but it still looks clunky to me especially the block to determine the right constructor. Does Java have a more streamlined way of executing this pattern?

Comment: Create a static variable in the class as private static HashMap<String, Class> potentialClasses also initialize in static scope of the class.

Comment: Please be much more specific about your use case.

Comment: I would probably go with a switch expression (new to Java 12): https://www.baeldung.com/java-switch

Comment: "Does Java have ...?" - It does not depend on Java. In any language you need to define somehow condition that connects conditions and class names.

Comment: Regardless of your solution that is not  how you compare Strings for equality.  Use `equals`

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion can be

```
public class CommonClass {
    private static HashMap<String, Class> potentialClasses = new HashMap<>();
    static { 
        potentialClasses.put("A", TypeA.class);
        potentialClasses.put("B", TypeB.class);
        potentialClasses.put("C", TypeC.class);
        potentialClasses.put("D", TypeD.class);
    }

    public static <T extends Common> T factory(String key) throws Exception {  
        Class[] cArg = new Class[1];
        cArg[0] = NecessaryConstructor.class;

        Class<T> classType = potentialClasses.getOrDefault(key, DefaultClass.class);
        return classType.getDeclaredConstructor(cArg).newInstance(descriptor);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

In case the logic is so simple as in your case, you may use reflection, without defining mapping:

```
public static Common factory(String key, InstantiationObj instantiationObj) {
    String className = "Type" + key;
    Class<T> classType = Class.forName(className);
    ...
```

Thus, for key "A" the variable *className* will have value "TypeA", for key "B" it will have value "TypeB", etc.

But this will work in this **simple** case  only, when mapping of parameter *key* to class names follows a simple pattern.

In case the logic becomes more complex later on, you would need `if (...)` clauses for every condition.

Answer (score 1):

One way I like implementing the factory pattern is with using spring. You can have as many classes of a specific type in your project.

Then, inject or autowire a List of same type in a class and Spring will set all instances of that type in the list.

Finally, transform the list to a map like you have and you will have maximized the idea of
“Closed for modification , open for extensibility” on you factory and project.

Comment: This is a Spring project, and I need to get better at “thinking in Spring”. I’ll see if I can get your suggestion working